# SQL Query + How to look back at a specific date

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, t-sql

I have a query that currently looks at receipts back 28 days from the date of purchase.

```
AND PAYMENT_DATE >= DATEADD(DD, -28, CONVERT(DATE, GETDATE()))
```

Now I this should go back to November 15 of the previous year, still using `PAYMENT_DATE`.

Is it possible to get help on how to accomplish this change?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not just hardcode `'2020-11-15'`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff because that only works when running the query *this* year but will fail when run again next year.

Comment: What happens if the current date is between November 15th and December 31st? Do you still want to go back more than a year?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just subtract a year from todays date and build a new date using [`DATEFROMPARTS`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/datefromparts-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

```
AND PAYMENT_DATE >= DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE())-1, 11, 15);
```

Comment: `Year( GetDate() ) - 1` seems a lot simpler than `DATEPART(year, DATEADD(year, -1, GETDATE()))`. Any reason to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

Use the follwing code

```
datediff(dd, PAYMENT_DATE, '20201115') = 0
```

Another approach

```
AND CONVERT(DATETIME, FLOOR(CONVERT(FLOAT, PAYMENT_DATE))) = '15/11/2020'
```